# Arabic font and wrap in wps office

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-studio, wps-office

I'm tring to use **WPS OFFICE SUITE** "KSOFFICE" on ubuntu

once started I found myself stacked with two problems related to Arabic language and not Engligh

word wrap is not functional and I need to do it myself

> you could see the difference in behavior in the table -_-

Also either installing from snap or ".deb" package Arabic fonts is read but not functional as you see in the image below

I'm installing font on system widely using ttf format and it could be reed by libre-office and it's functional

but I need a compatible software with MS OFFICE, also user interface seems to be beter

**is there any fix for any of both issuses ?**

first screenshot (arabic word wrapping)
[image]

second screenshot (arabic "hindi" numbers are loaded but not used)
[image]

Comment: Why the libreoffice tag?

Comment: Both programs run on the same env but have different behavior.. I wondered that someone who knows both applications could know why - @David

Comment: Even if they are similar programs, that doesn't mean a solution for one will work for the other.  WPS Office isn't distributed with Ubuntu...you should contact thd developer instead for help.

Comment: not the solution what I only want but the difference between behavior with fonts to prevent it in the future or even make a request for the developers to take care.. this issue makes a powerful application useless